# Why does my page change color immediately after unchecking save color box

Tags: javascript

I have a color changer as a little added feature for my application, when the user clicks the color changer on the elements will change colors whenever the user clicks in the body. The bug is very minor and isnt code breaking its just annoying and I cant seem to figure out a work around it.... When the user clicks on the save color button to pause the color changer everything is fine but immediately after un checking the save color button the page changes color. I want it to halt changing colors until the next click after unchecking the save color button..

```
class ColorVar {
    static instances = [];
    constructor(label, oCode) {
        this.label = label;
        this.oCode = oCode;
        ColorVar.instances.push(this);
        this.paused = false; // Add a 'paused' property to track the pause state
    }
    changeFn() {
        if (this.paused) return; // Check if the color change is paused
        let rVal = () => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        };
        let r = rVal();
        let g = rVal();
        let b = rVal();
        let clrCode = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
        document.body.style.setProperty(this.label, clrCode);
    }
    cResetFn() {
        document.body.style.setProperty(this.label, this.oCode);
    }
    togglePause() {
        this.paused = !this.paused; // Toggle the 'paused' state
    }
}

const color1 = new ColorVar("--color1", "#b4e8b4");
const color2 = new ColorVar("--color2", "#1f1f7c");
const color3 = new ColorVar("--color5", "#fc8eac");

const colorSwitch = document.getElementById('colorSwitch');
const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pauseButton'); // Add a pause button
const pauseLabel = document.getElementById('pauseLabel');

colorSwitch.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (colorSwitch.checked && !pauseButton.checked) {
        // Show the pause button and label using Tailwind CSS classes
        pauseLabel.classList.remove('hidden');
        pauseButton.classList.remove('hidden');
        document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
            ColorVar.instances.forEach(colorVar => colorVar.changeFn());
        });
    } else {
        ColorVar.instances.forEach(colorVar => colorVar.cResetFn());
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', () => {
            ColorVar.instances.forEach(colorVar => colorVar.changeFn());
        });
        // Hide the pause button and label using Tailwind CSS classes
        pauseLabel.classList.add('hidden');
        pauseButton.classList.add('hidden');
    }
});
pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Toggle the pause state for all ColorVar instances
    ColorVar.instances.forEach(colorVar => colorVar.togglePause());
});
```

Comment: The event listeners are never removed, see how to use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Tip: Anonymous function creates an unique reference to the function, to remove an event listener, you'll need a reference to the same function. Store your event handlers into variables/declared functions, or into object properties.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the way you attach and remove the event listener for the click event on the document.body. You're attaching it using an anonymous function:

```
document.body.removeEventListener('click', () => {
    ColorVar.instances.forEach(colorVar => colorVar.changeFn());
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to solve the issue from the question? If you don't have a solution to the issue of the question please post a comment.